# Can I develop an Angular 5 app using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm new in web dev, and I am currently reading about Angular, and other frameworks. I know that Angular is written in TypeScript, but I'm wondering if it is possible to develop an app using Angular and JavaScript?

Comment: Yes. the question is: why would you want to do that?

Comment: This question shows a clear lack of research.  The answer is in the official documentation at https://angular.io/docs:  >"Most Angular code can be written with just the latest JavaScript, using types for dependency injection, and using decorators for metadata."

Comment: I agree, but since when did SO become so "hawkish" about people asking basic questions? He said he was new. I remember being new to the vast abyss that is anything javascript, a basic question like this actually becomes pretty complicated, pretty quickly.

Comment: it was better you read about a full course of java script and type script from scratch.

Comment: Not cool to jump on someone for asking a question -- and btw, this is a legit question.

Answer (score 3):

> As TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript, existing JavaScript programs are also valid TypeScript programs.

([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TypeScript))

Meaning, All JavaScript is valid TypeScript. TypeScript only **adds** thing to the JavaScript language, you are not required to use these new features such as Types, you can skip them and just type normal JavaScript.

**However**, when you develop Angular applications you become a user of the `@angular-cli` package and tool which helps you generate boilerplate code for your files and projects. This code that is generated by the CLI is written using TypeScript features -- So if you for some reason refuse to use TypeScript, it will make your development experience worse since you will not be able to use all of the Angular tools that help your development, such as the CLI or the Documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Angular does use `.ts` files by default. But if you write simple javascript code in them it will still work. Valid javascript is also valid typescript.

Once you get up and running with angular though you will see the benefits of Typescript are worth it. It won't make sense to write an Angular app using just javascript.

Answer (score 2):

The question you should ask yourself is why would you do that? TypeScript became a standard for large front-end applications. It stays ahead of the curve of EcmaScript, bringing more features that are only going to become part of the standard and then implemented. Not to mention static types, which ensure all sorts of runtime errors just never happen.

Also, TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript, you can write your ol' regular JS in `.ts` files and never worry about all the goodness TypeScript gives you if that is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can but it would not be **sophisticated and well-timed** application If you want to avoid Typescript. Even ECMAScript 2017 also very similar to Typescript. So, It would be definitely better to go ahead with Typescript.

Answer (score 0):

**Introduction to Angular concepts**

Angular is a platform and framework for building single-page client applications using HTML and TypeScript. Angular is written in TypeScript. It implements core and optional functionality as a set of TypeScript libraries that you import into your apps

[read more](https://angular.io/guide/architecture)